# Echo a date in input type inside a echo with Y-M-D format

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement, echo

I already echo a date but it doesn't have a right format for me which is Y-M-D I already specify the format on my variable but when I call the variable to be a value of my input type on my echo it doesn't give the right format. Hope someone help me . Here is my code

```
<?php
$last_covered=strtotime("+3 Months"); date("Y-m-d", $last_covered);
if ($statusv=='Newly-Registered') echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='last_covered' value ='".$last_covered."'>";
```

Comment: What date format is you needed? You specified `Y-m-d` which in case output is `0000-00-00`.

Comment: `date` does not change the value of the passed variable. You need to assign the output to a variable i.e. `$last_covered=date("Y-m-d", $last_covered);`

Comment: Already have an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may try this

```
<?php
$last_covered = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 Months"));
if (!empty($statusv) && ($statusv=='Newly-Registered')) {
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='last_covered' value ='".$last_covered."'>";
} else {}
?>
```

---

you have undefined variable on **echo line** 
may fix variable **$last_covred** to **$last_covered**

Answer (score 1):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a **Unix timestamp**

and

[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer **timestamp** or the current time if no timestamp is given.

So to synchronize both `strtotime()` and `date()`, you can do it this way-

```
$last_covered=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+3 Months"));
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/FpqZO